# Format datastring to Excel

Tags: python, excel, csv

I want to write the data I receive through serial to a CSV file so I can handle it further in Excel. Retrieving the data works but when writing it to a CSV file the output is not in the format that I want.

The code I use is:

```py
ser.write('WER?\r\n'.encode())
meetgegevens = ser.readline()
m_str = str(meetgegevens)
print(m_str)
lst = list(m_str.split(';'))
print(lst)

with open('meetgegevens.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerows(lst)
```

The output of `print(m_str)` is:

```
b'WERTEx=16:>310.0M\xea;17:>310.0M\xea;18:>310.0M\xea;19:>310.0M\xea;20:>310.0M\xea;21:>310.0M\xea;24:00.01mA;25:00.01mA;26:00.01mA;27:00.01mA;28:00.01mA;29:00.05mA;30:00.12mA;58:228.2V;59:050.0Hz;62:226.5V;63:227.2V;81:00.12?;96:0535.V;97:0535.V;98:0535.V;\r\n'
```

The output of `print(lst)` is:

```
["b'WERTEx=16:>310.0M\\xea", '17:>310.0M\\xea', '18:>310.0M\\xea', '19:>310.0M\\xea', '20:>310.0M\\xea', '21:>310.0M\\xea', '24:00.01mA', '25:00.01mA', '26:00.01mA', '27:00.01mA', '28:00.01mA', '29:00.05mA', '30:00.12mA', '58:228.2V', '59:050.0Hz', '62:226.5V', '63:227.2V', '81:00.12?', '96:0535.V', '97:0535.V', '98:0535.V', "\\r\\n'"]
```

The data in the list is formatted as `'address: value'`. I would like to write it to a CSV file where every list object is on a new row in the following format: row1 column1 contains the address and row 1 column 2 contains the value.

Thus far I'm only able to get each list item on a new row but it's in one column and every character is followed by a comma.

Does somebody know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You should show the expected data in csv...

Comment: Read up on [bytes.decode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode)

Comment: Thank you stovfl, I will do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import csv
m_str = 'WERTEx=16:>310.0M\xea;17:>310.0M\xea;18:>310.0M\xea;19:>310.0M\xea;20:>310.0M\xea;21:>310.0M\xea;24:00.01mA;25:00.01mA;26:00.01mA;27:00.01mA;28:00.01mA;29:00.05mA;30:00.12mA;58:228.2V;59:050.0Hz;62:226.5V;63:227.2V;81:00.12?;96:0535.V;97:0535.V;98:0535.V;\r\n'

lst = list(m_str.split(';'))

myCsvData = []
for word in lst:
    split = word.split(':')
    try:
        row = [split[0], split[1]]
        myCsvData.append(row)
    except:
        pass

print(myCsvData)
with open('meetgegevens.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in myCsvData:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Something for you to continue with..

Comment: Thank you Hillborn. Your solution fixed the comma problem but every row is still in one column.

Comment: Isn't that part of the strategy of beeing a 'comma separated file'. Excel will not make it into columns until you exec the "text to columns" and chose separator 'comma' @LodewijkTol

Comment: I tried text to columns and it works perfectly. Thank you so much.